# C++ scoped enums that are implicitly convertable to integers

Tags: c++, enums

I have a question about the different forms of `enum`s and `enum class`'s, specifically to specify a large number of (scoped!) constants.

I was wondering if there is a way to declare a *scoped enum*, which is *implicitly convertable* to an integer. A usecase for this would be to specify register adresses and to be able to access them with something like `MY_REGISTERS::FOO`.

Here are the options that I know of and have encountered, please imagine a function with the signature `void do_something(uint32_t bla)` exists.

#### 1: `enum class`

Enum class is scoped, but not implicitly convertable to an integer. I find it important that I don't have to `static_cast` it to an integer so this doesn't seem like the right fit.

```
enum class Foo : uint32_t
{
    BAR = 0x0000,
    BAZ = 0x0001
};

do_something(Foo::BAR) // Illegal, I'd have to `static_cast` here
```

#### 2: `enum`

A regular C styled enum is implicitly convertable to an integer, but is not scoped (and pollutes the namespace it's in). Here is an example of why I find this undesirable for my usecase:

```
enum Foo : uint32_t
{
    BAR = 0x0000,
    BAZ = 0x0001
}

do_something(Foo::BAR) // Legal, and what I am looking for
do_something(BAR)      // Legal, whilst I don't want this to be possible
```

#### 3: namespaced `enum`

This works, but if I encountered this somewhere, I'd raise an eyebrow. Something tells me there may be a better way

```
namespace Foo
{
    enum dontcare : uint32_t
    {
        BAR = 0x0000,
        BAZ = 0x0001
    };
}

do_something(Foo::BAR) // Legal, and what I am looking for
do_something(BAR)      // Illegal, just like I want it to be
```

#### 4: namespaced `static constexpr`

Although this does what I want, I again (just like with the namespaced `enum`) feel like there must be a better way.

```
namespace Foo
{
    static constexpr uint32_t BAR = 0x0000,
    static constexpr uint32_t BAZ = 0x0001
}

do_something(Foo::BAR) // Legal, and what I am looking for
do_something(BAR)      // Illegal, just like I want it to be
```

So, all in all, is there a better way for this or will I have to stick to either namespaced `enum`s or namespaced `constexpr`s?

Comment: If you don't need to access the type of the enum, most people would probably go with option 3, but make the enum anonymous (`enum { ... }`). You see this done in some type trait implementations.

Comment: One of the reasons scoped enums were created is so that they wouldn't be implicitly convertible to integers.

Comment: `I find it important that I don't have to static_cast` Explicit is better than implicit (the Zen of Python).

Comment: @AndyG correct, but if you use enums for the declaration of integer constants, then the strong typing becomes less relevant (since C++ integers itself are not strongly typed). I also see scoping and type weakness as 2 separate issues/subjects, whilst `enum class` gives me an "All or nothing" solution.

Comment: `I'd raise an eyebrow` I see this pattern quite often in C++98 code-bases. Unfortunately, this is as close as one can get to the `class enum` goodness without C++11.

Comment: What is the problem with 3)? The only critique would be that accessing the enum type inconvenient. But as you named it dontcare, I think that's not a problem for you. So, 3) is a good solution, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hack your own scoped enum by mixing a `struct` with a nested anonymous enum (Edit: I guess the enum itself doesn't *have* to be anonymous):

```
struct Foo{
    enum: uint32_t
    {
        BAR = 0x0000,
        BAZ = 0x0001
    };
};
```

#### [Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/xkuE4XVzJtJUIZV9)

It's not a *scoped enum* as per C++11 semantics ([dcl.enum]), but it's at least an enum that is scoped to the `Foo` class. And it's usable like how you want without polluting the global namespace:

```
do_something(Foo::BAR);
```

Comment: To me this feels like abusing the `struct` keyword for its scoping since this gives you a bunch of (unused) unrelated features with it (constructors destructors etc). It's essentially the same as the namespace example, but with a different semantic meaning.

Comment: @McMuffinton one advantage that `struct` has over `namespace` is that it enables creating enums nested in other classes. If this is not needed, namespace is a superior alternative, yes.

Comment: @McMuffinton: Yes it is essentially the same as the namespace example. However, it more closely aligns with how a scoped enum works. You can't pollute the global namespace with a `using struct Foo` here because it's illegal, but you could `using namespace Foo` if we went that direction.

Comment: @AndyG Ah, I hadn't thought of it that way yet, it does indeed distinguish them! Kind of feels like we're working around something the language provides at that point though, but thanks for the clarification!